# How to get items in asynchronous environment in different components?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, eventemitter

I have main component with this code(without imports):

```
class AppComponent {
    products = null;
    productsUpdated = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(product_service: ProductService) {
        this._product_service = product_service;

        this._product_service.getList()
            .then((products) => {
                this.products = products;
                this.productsUpdated.emit(products)
            });
    }
}
```

With template:
    `<left-sidenav [productsReceived]="productsUpdated"></left-sidenav>`

And component for sorting products:

```
class LeftSidenavComponent {
    @Input() productsReceived;
    @Output() productsSorted = new EventEmitter();

    categories = []

    constructor(product_list_service: ProductListService) {
        this._product_list_service = product_list_service;
    }            
    ngOnInit() {
        this.productsReceived.subscribe((products) => {
            this.categories = products.map((elem) => {
                return elem.category
            })
        });
    }
}
```

So when all is drawn, `categories` array in `LeftSidenavComponent` is empty.
I think that `productUpdated` event emitter fires earlier than `LeftSidenavComponent` subscribes to it, but don't know how to handle that.

Comment: Try this tweak to start with
@Output() productsUpdated = new EventEmitter(); If you continue to have problems, create a plunker.

Comment: I recommend [not to have promises inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) at all. The problem is the same with emitting events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend moving the `EventEmitter`'s to the service you have injected like

```
@Injectable()
    export class DrinksService {
    drinkSelected = new EventEmitter<any>();
    drinkChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();
    drinksToggle = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

The above code is an example from one of my projects, but just change the variable names.

This way rather then relying on the `HTML` template to modify `productsReceived`, you simply subscribe to the eventEmitters in `ngOnInit`.

Currently, your code is using databinding to an event emitter `productsUpdated` but you could simply databind `[productsReceived]="productsUpdated"` where `productsUpdated` is an empty list. Once `productsUpdated` is populated with values, it will be reflected in the DOM. You have to populate `productsUpdated` by subscribing to an event emitter like...

```
this.myEmitter
    .subscribe(
        (data)=>this.productsUpdated = data
    );
```

Does this help? The main thing is to databind to a list, and not an event emitter.